# What is the definition of Plancherel density?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, definitions

I know about the Plancherel measure, but I don't know where the term "Plancherel density" is defined.

Comment: Where did you encounter it?

Comment: @LSpice For $p$-adic groups Aubert and Plymen have some papers on explicit Plancherel measures for $GL_n$ and other groups. Their theorem gives a formula for the Plancherel density. I think it's a function of the discrete series representation of a Levi. Is it just the Plancherel measure of the singleton?

Comment: Can you give a specific paper?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X04001633. They explicitly compute the Plancherel density with respect to a given measure on the tempered dual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Plancherel density is derived from the Plancherel measure, see [arXiv:1812.00047](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00047) for the precise definition:

[image]